# Building C library (FFmpeg) with Android NDK r17: undefined reference to '__mulodi4'

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ndk, clang, sanitizer, libgcc

My problem happens to be with FFmpeg but I suspect that this would happen with almost any C library.

### Problem Description

My app uses FFmpeg that is compiled with NDK r10e. I am trying to update everything to NDK r17, while also switching to clang, since Google prefers us to use that over gcc.

My first step is to just build FFmpeg.

To that end, I have used the `make_standalone_toolchain.py` script to create a stand-alone toolchain for the x86 architecture, like so:

```
make_standalone_toolchain.py --arch x86 --api 21 --install-dir ~/Development/ndk-toolchains/x86
```

Then I configure the FFmpeg build as follows:

```
TOOLCHAIN_DIR=~/Development/ndk-toolchains/x86

./configure \
--prefix=$(pwd)/android/x86 \
--cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN_DIR/bin/i686-linux-android- \
--target-os=android \
--arch=x86 \
--enable-cross-compile \
--disable-asm \
--toolchain=clang-usan \
--disable-stripping \
--extra-cflags="-m32" \
--sysroot=$TOOLCHAIN_DIR/sysroot/
```

And then I build it as follows:

```
make clean
make -j4
make install
```

Everything seems to compile fine, but I get several linker errors that all say the same thing:

> undefined reference to '__mulodi4'

### Solutions I've tried

#### 1. Linking against libclang_rt.builtins*

I found a few places around the Web which suggested that this is caused by the fact that libgcc doesn't provide `__mulodi4`. A github user named sitsofe was nice enough to post a work-around [here](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/184). However, I am sure where to find this `libclang_rt.builtins-i686.a` library. Here is what I was able to find in my standalone toolchain directory:

> ./lib64/clang/6.0.2/lib/linux/libclang_rt.builtins-x86_64.a
>   ./lib64/clang/6.0.2/lib/linux/libclang_rt.builtins-i386.a
>   ./lib64/clang/6.0.2/lib/linux/libclang_rt.builtins-aarch64-android.a
>   ./lib64/clang/6.0.2/lib/linux/libclang_rt.builtins-mips64-android.a
>   ./lib64/clang/6.0.2/lib/linux/libclang_rt.builtins-x86_64-android.a
>   ./lib64/clang/6.0.2/lib/linux/libclang_rt.builtins-i686-android.a
>   ./lib64/clang/6.0.2/lib/linux/libclang_rt.builtins-arm-android.a
>   ./lib64/clang/6.0.2/lib/linux/libclang_rt.builtins-mips-android.a

The `libclang_rt.builtins-i686-android.a` library looks close but (I think) no cigar. When I try to link to it, I get the same error:

> undefined reference to '__mulodi4'

Here is my new FFmpeg build config command:

```
./configure \
--prefix=$(pwd)/android/x86 \
--cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN_DIR/bin/i686-linux-android- \
--target-os=android \
--arch=x86 \
--enable-cross-compile \
--disable-asm \
--toolchain=clang-usan \
--disable-stripping \
--extra-cflags="-m32" \
--extra-ldflags="-L${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/lib64/clang/6.0.2/lib/linux/libclang_rt.builtins-i686-android.a" \
--sysroot=$TOOLCHAIN_DIR/sysroot/
```

I checked with `-v` to make sure that this line was added to the linker flags, and it was. However, I have no idea if this library should even be expected to work, let alone whether I'm adding it to the linker flags correctly. In any case, what I'm doing here doesn't work.

#### 2. Switching to a different sanitizer

Instead of using the undefined sanitizer, I tried switching to the address sanitizer. This is (frankly) a total stab in the dark, based on a vague mention of asan being available in r17 at Google I/O this week.

In this case, FFmpeg builds just fine!

However, when I try to pull FFmpeg into my test project (a simple AAR w/ C++ support, that just has one jni method that calls `av_gettime()`, I get a ton of linker errors:

> Error:error: undefined reference to '__asan_option_detect_stack_use_after_return'
>   Error:error: undefined reference to '__asan_stack_malloc_0'
>   Error:error: undefined reference to '__asan_report_load4'
>   Error:error: undefined reference to '__asan_report_load4'
>   Error:error: undefined reference to '__asan_shadow_memory_dynamic_address'
>   Error:error: undefined reference to '__asan_option_detect_stack_use_after_return'
>   Error:error: undefined reference to '__asan_stack_malloc_0'
>   Error:error: undefined reference to '__asan_report_load4'
>   Error:error: undefined reference to '__asan_report_load4'
>   Error:error: undefined reference to '__asan_shadow_memory_dynamic_address'
>   Error:error: undefined reference to '__asan_option_detect_stack_use_after_return'
>   Error:error: undefined reference to '__asan_stack_malloc_0'
>   Error:error: undefined reference to '__asan_report_store4'
>   Error:error: undefined reference to '__asan_report_store4'
>   Error:error: undefined reference to '__asan_init'
>   Error:error: undefined reference to '__asan_version_mismatch_check_v9'

So it seems to find the FFmpeg library just fine, indicating that that part of my CMake file is correct, but it can't locate any of these asan references.

This seems to be a common problem that people are running into, but I can't see to find a work-around that actually works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: update to NDK r17.

This is referred to in a handful of NDK bugs:

- https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/184
- https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/294 (the root cause, not the same symptom)
- https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/506

Essentially Clang was generating calls that libgcc doesn't implement. I say *was* rather than *is* because this doesn't seem to be the case any more for NDK r17 for this specific function.

In the event that you're still hitting this and I just wasn't able to with any of the earlier test cases, you can try linking with `-lcompiler_rt-extras`. This is included as of NDK r17 and has the missing functions.

Comment: Thank you. I actually am using NDK r17 -- `source.properties` says `Pkg.Desc = Android NDK` and `Pkg.Revision = 17.0.4698735-beta2`. I tried adding `-lcompiler_rt-extras` and also verified that there is a `-L` argument for the folder in which `libcompiler_rt-extras.a` can be found, but no dice. I still get `undefined reference to '__mulodi4'`. I don't see any other errors.

Comment: If interested, I have a way to repeat this:

(1) Create toolchain: `make_standalone_toolchain.py --arch x86 --api 21 --install-dir ~/your-toolchains-dir/x86`
(2) Clone FFmpeg: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git
(3) `cd FFmpeg`, run `./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/android/x86 --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN_DIR/bin/i686-linux-android- --target-os=android --arch=x86 --enable-cross-compile --disable-asm --toolchain=clang-usan --disable-stripping --extra-cflags="-m32" --extra-ldflags="-v -lcompiler_rt-extras" --sysroot=$TOOLCHAIN_DIR/sysroot`
(4) `make clean`
(5) `make -j4`
(6) `make install`

Comment: Thanks for the repro case. I've left myself a note to see if there's a workaround for the ffmpeg case. You may want to check to make sure that `-lcompiler_rt-extras` was linked in the right order. If it's linked before the library that needs it, it will have no effect.